# Kernel dies again and again

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-kernel

I'm working with python in Jupyter notebook using virtualenv in Ubuntu 16.04 but as soon I create a new file the kernel dies and it happens again and again. [This happens although I restarted the whole process again for several times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdJA6.png)

Comment: Anything in the console, where you started the notebook server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message isn't very descriptive; console output would be very helpful. But I have suspicions you can look into:

First, try increasing memory and cpu for your virtual machine. I have a feeling that the kernel is simply getting starved out.

The other question ([sic] suspicion) I have for you is did you have successful runs with Notebook in the past? If the answer is no, there's probably something wrong with the installation.

Comment: No, it was my first time. But everything works fine if I run the programs from terminal.

Comment: Found it! There was problem during installation. Removed jupyter and then updated ipython and installed jupyter again and it worked.